# Python - Comparing text files and what if the first 9 characters match the whole string goes to a new text file

Tags: python

I have a screipt that can read to text files and compare them, and whatever matches it writes that string to a new text file. It works however I have an issue as somethimes not the entire line matches. II am compare a file with part numbers that look like this `X00TB0001` to a file with the same numbers but with `_01` to indicate its a different photo. So I would like to make this script so that if I have `X00TB0001` and `X00TB0001_01` that both get moved to this new file not just the exact match.

Here is my script:

```
with open('NewPics.txt') as file1:
  with open('PartNums.csv') as file2:
        Same = open('PicsWeHave.txt','w')
        common_lines = set(file1.readlines()) & set(file2.readlines())
        for line in common_lines:
              Same.write(line)
```

Comment: Which file contains the part numbers without the suffix (i.e. without the `_01`)? Can it be assumed that every line of `NewPics.csv` and `PartNums.csv` always start with the part number or do they have column names, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can straight match the first N characters (9 in this example):

```
from collections import defaultdict

chars2match = 9
with open('NewPics.txt') as file1, open('PartNums.csv') as file2, open('PicsWeHave.txt','w') as Same:
    # any other text extraction would work here, e.g. regexp
    newpics = defaultdict(set)
    for line in file1:
        newpics[line[:chars2match]].add(line)
    partnums = defaultdict(set)
    for line in file2:
        partnums[line[:chars2match]].add(line)
    common_lines = set().union(
        *(lines for key, lines in newpics.items() if key in partnums)
    ).union(
        *(lines for key, lines in partnums.items() if key in newpics)
    )

    Same.writelines(common_lines)
```

Comment: From the problem description I believe the relationship between `PartNums` to `NewPics` is 1 to many.

Comment: @nonDucor thank you, I didn't catch that. Updated the answer

Comment: So when I got to ass a `'\n'` to the writelines part i get an error. im trying to keep everything on a new line, how would I do this?

Comment: There is a typo in `if key in partums`, should be `if key in partnums` correct?

Comment: yes thats right I fixed it in my script I didn't notice it right away. Do you know how to make everything go on a separate line?

Comment: @PyMan  remove `.strip()` from dict comphrehensions. I've updated the answer

Comment: I see it only does one of them. for example `X00TB0001` and `X00TB0001_01`. There is 36 diffrent ones such as `X00TB0001_01, X00TB0001_02 ... X00TB0001_36` how would I get that